# Finding the image of a complex function: $w(z)=e^{iz^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis

What is a good method for finding the image of a complex function? For example, I'm trying to find the image of $$w(z)=e^{iz^2}$$
I have tried writing $z=x+iy$, so $z^2 = x^2 +2ixy -y^2$, and
$$w=\vert w \vert e^{i\theta}=e^{i(x^2-y^2)}e^{-2xy}$$
which implies that $\vert w \vert \in \mathbb{R_0}$, and $\theta \in \mathbb{R}$, but this is nonsense of course?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your $w$ is holomorphic in the entire complex plane, so [Picard's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem) says its range is *either* a single point, *or* all of $\mathbb C$ *or* $\mathbb C$ with a single point excluded.

Since your function is clearly not constant, and -- also clearly -- never takes the value $0$, the only possibility for its range is $\mathbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: And is my argument correct as well?

Comment: @fawningflagellum: It doesn't look like much of an argument to me. You don't seem to conclude anything about $0$ not being in the range, and it's quite unclear how you conclude that $(x,y)\mapsto(x^2-y^2,-2xy)$ is sufficiently surjective to cater for all other points.

Comment: Can someone explain why the function isn't just rotating around in a circle forever? I guess I don't understand the notation.

Comment: @ElliotG: $z$ is complex, so $iz^2$ is not necessarily pure imaginary.

Comment: Sort of a large gun for such a little problem...

Comment: @HenningMakholm I reasoned that for two complex numbers to be equal, they should have equal moduli (and consequently also arguments)?

Comment: Ohh thanks. I was thinking of real values

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: Yes, but quicker (at least for me) to deploy than something that depends on actually thinking about what the function is, deeper than making sure it is elementary and defined everywhere.

Comment: @fawningflagellum: Something like that would be the right direction to go in if you're trying to prove that the function is _injective_. (Though it is not even completely right then; if the arguments differ by $2\pi$ the numbers can still be equal). But that's the opposite of what you need to do here. You must prove that _any given_ nonzero number arises as a function value -- there's no way you can get from there to thinking about two numbers being equal.

Answer (score 2):

For every $p\in\Bbb C$ there exists $z\in\Bbb C$ with $iz^2=p$. So the range of your function is the same as the range of the exponential function, which is $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.